# Highcharts, detect if point is first in stack

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have a highchart where I would like to display datalabels only on the first point of each stack (i.e. where the 0 point is)

my config looks like:

```
{

  chart: {type: 'bar'},

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'percent',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        allowOverlap: true,
        formatter: function () {
          if (pointIsFirstInStack(this)) {
            return labelFunction(this);
          }
          return '';
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
     name: 'Available',
     data: [
       {x: 'Event1', y: 18},
       {x: 'Event2', y: 20}
     ]
  }, {
    name: 'Purchased',
    data: [
      {x: 'Event1', y: 23},
      {x: 'Event2', y: 40}
    ]
  }]
}
```

But I'm having a hard time implementing the `pointIsFirstInStack` function, any ideas?

regards,

Einar

JSFiddle to illustrate my chart: http://jsfiddle.net/qam37suh/

edit: added series and stacking to the config example
edit2: added JSFiddle

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mzy0wadb/)?

Comment: Can you post the entire chart configuration? I'd like to see how is your data stacked

Comment: I added more config for you @LucaRegazzi

Comment: If the stack order never changes it's easy to accomplish. 

You can just disable the datalables globally and then just enable them on the first stacked series [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qam37suh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the series index.

If you are always going to have two series, you can check it like this:

```
formatter: function(){
  return this.series.index == 1 ? this.x : null;
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jL6zrt7d/

Highcharts stacks the series in reverse by default, so index 0 is stacked on the top.

If you are going to have a dynamic number of series, you can add a check for the number of series first, so that you are still checking for the last series:

```
formatter: function(){
  var len = this.series.chart.series.length -1;
  return this.series.index == len ? this.x : null;
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jL6zrt7d/1/

( You could also set `reversedStacks: false` on your `yAxis`, and instead just check for `index == 0`

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jL6zrt7d/3/

)

Or, if your goal is to put the categories inside the series instead of outside, you could just move them:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Event1', 'Event2'],
  labels: {
    x: 60,
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)'
    }
   }
 }
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jL6zrt7d/2/

Comment: Awesome, that worked... wasn't aware of the reverse stacking thing